# Updating the data stored in the database(python+ Beautiful Soup+mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code every time every hour, it takes information like, price-profile-photo, etc. from sites and stores in the database.
But the problem is that the information is repeated every two hours and the data volume is increased in the database.
Is there a way to pinpoint, for example, if the price of a TV on the main site is changed, only the price of the TV in the database will be updated?

Comment: Can you change the main site to add a timestamp? And are you inserting to the database rather than updating?

Comment: _Can you change the main site to add a timestamp?_ **what do you mean?**      _And are you inserting to the database rather than updating?_  **The point is, I do not know how to do this.**